# Acess local Burp proxy from WSL

Tags: apache, proxy, localhost, wsl-2, burp

My issue is rather simple: How do I configure my setup, so that my WSL (2) instance (ubuntu) could access and use a proxy server served using Burp Suite on the same physical computer, but on the Windows side?

Currently I am getting connection refused, whatever I do. The proxy obviously works fine if I test it in windows.

The proxy is setup to redirect `localhost:3001 --> localhost:80`. This is where it gets a bit tangly, as the `localhost:80` server is in fact running on the WSL instance too.

So basically, I would like a program, FFUF in this case, on WSL to be able to send a request through my Burp Proxy which is on Windows. The proxy then redirects the request back to WSL to the apache2 server that is running there.

```
WSL (FFUF) --> Windows (Burp proxy) --> WSL (Apache at :80)
```

I believe there is something I am missing regarding localhost and what is `localhost` in what case.

`localhost` from Windows seems to work to reference services running on WSL, but I am not sure it works the other way around...
I have tried using `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, and the LAN IP of Windows as mentioned in the virtual WSL network. No luck from WSL side yet.

My apache is setup to listen to `0.0.0.0:80`